# how xcodebuild to pass WARNING_CFLAGS to buildsettings

Tags: c++, ios, xcodebuild

xcodebuild -project MyProj.xcodeproj -scheme MyLib WARNING_CFLAGS='-Wno-shorten-64-to-32

It seems like not workable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to Build Phases of your Xcode project.
2. In compile sources, select all files you want to compress the error for
3. Add `-Wno-shorten-64-to-32` to the "Compiler Flags" column